# how to typecast a boolean value to bit field in c

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bit-fields

I am using cpp for programming AVR microcontroller.
 
My issue is:

- I have a structure of bit field having 2 members, each of 1 bit.
- A simple structure of Boolean variables.

While transferring the value from Boolean structure member to a bit field member, do I need to typecast bool variable into a bit field? 
Would this conversion lead to warnings, as both are 1 bit variables?

Comment: a small code example would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your two boolean values are `workIsFinished` and `customerIsInsane`, and the equivalent bit fields are `doneWorking` and `madUser`.

You can simply do something like:

```
doneWorking = workIsFinished ? 1 : 0;
madUser = customerIsInsane ? 1 : 0;
```

without having to worry about casting or any of that stuff. Any compiler worth its salt will be able to optimise that pretty thoroughly.